# Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value (getting this error , i am using trezorjs)

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin, trezor

I am using trezorjs library. I am creating transactions at ropstan but i get this error again and again . Could anyone help me out int this issue.

```
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
    at Object.InvalidResponse (web3.min.js:1)
    at web3.min.js:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.r.onreadystatechange (web3.min.js:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have enough ether for the transaction? That error occurs when you **don't have enough ether** for sending the transaction.

Comment: I have 2 ether. I am sending this transaction after getting signed from hardware wallet using trezorjs.

Comment: are you familiar with signing transaction using trezorjs?